# Password Protect Winforms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, security, systray

I have a simple WinForms application that runs in the system tray. Is it possible to password protect the program from closing if a user tries to close it from task manager?

Ideally I want to keep a user from closing the process but if windows is restarted, I want it to close without being prompted. Much like antivirus programs.

Comment: Did you try fiddling around with `FromClosing` event? You can make use of the `FormClosingEventArgs`'s `Cancel` property control form closing. Setting `Cancel` to `false` would restrict the app from being closed. `CloseReason` property indicates why the form is being closed (this is an enum `Systems.Windows.Forms.CloseReason`).

Answer (score 0):

If a user has the correct permissions they will be able to kill your process from the Task Manager.

That said as @fujiFX mentions in his comment the [FormClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event is a good start and better than nothing.

> The [FormClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event occurs as the form is being closed. When a form is closed, it is disposed, releasing all resources associated with the form. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. To cancel the closure of a form, set the `Cancel` property of the [FormClosingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) passed to your event handler to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do, but you can create two applications, one is main program and two is helper. If helper is killed, then main app restarts it. If main app is killed, then helper restarts main app.

Answer (score -1):

You can make this verification on YourService.Stop method (assuming you're using a Windows Service thus inheriting from ServiceBase), but as far as I know you cannot prevent the user from killing the proccess, just to close the app (two different things in Windows).